# more or less pager - how to quit

Tags: apt, upgrade, less, pager

Idiotic question of the day

On Ubuntu 12.04 server console, I've run an `apt-get update` followed by an `apt-get upgrade`

Everything was going swimmingly; when it got to **MySQL**, it warned me it was about to overwrite the `my.conf` file which I had changed.

One of the options offered was to show the differences between the two files. All well and good and now I remember why I changed it and will do the same again to the new one.

But I can't figure out how to `exit` the display of the differences and carry on. I believe I've tried every possible key combination, and only succeeded in suspending the `apt-get` job. When I fg, it comes back and pressing return redisplays the annoing end tag of the difference display:

```
(END)
```

Please help while I still have some hair left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually just the standard pager program (i.e. `less` or `more`) and the key to quit is just <kbd>q</kbd>