# Error installing anaconda on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, anaconda

I am trying to install anaconda on kubuntu but I keep getting this error in the attached picture.

What could be the issue?[kubuntu terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q8A5.png)

Comment: press the "q" key and continue.

Comment: it worked,,,,Thanks

Comment: Related: [more or less pager - how to quit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586501/more-or-less-pager-how-to-quit)